# ExpressJs route and display page on Vanilla jS

Tags: javascript, express

if i make a request to 
`app.get("/auth/login", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/authentication/login.html"));
});`

using

```
fetch("/auth/login", {
      method: "GET"
    });
```

i receive as response the html page , but how can i display it to the screen (i heard document.write is a bad practice).
And where should the routes redirections be done? client or server?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var myVar = document.getElementById("id_element");

myVar.innerHTML(jsonResponse.key);
```

Where

```
jsonResponse.key
```

Is result of your fetched and stringified data

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you mean to visit that route in your browser. The browser knows how to render it. So open up a browser and enter the route.

localhost:port/auth/login

Routes that render pages are not meant to be called with fetch or axios or other request libraries. Unless you have a specific use case for it. Which is rare.